# How to install Android Emulator on Azure VM

Tags: android-emulator, appium, azure-virtual-machine, virtualization

I wanted to install Android Emulator on Azure VM. Gone through various reference even posted on stackoverflow but not found a solid answer. Please help to understand whether it is possible or not? If yes how can we achieve that